# Link pod in Podfile to a specific target

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoapods

Here is my podfile, is it possible to link the FXForms pod only to the "MainTarget" target?

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.0'
pod "AFNetworking"
pod 'CryptoCoding', "~> 1.1"
pod 'FXForms'
pod "FDKeychain", "~> 1.0.0"
pod 'SVProgressHUD'

link_with 'MainTarget', 'ExtensionTarget'
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing easier than that:

```
target :MainTarget do
    pod 'FXForms'
end
```

For more infos see [CocoaPods documentation](https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/the-podfile.html)

Comment: Do I still keep the `link_with`?

Comment: If you don't wrap the other pods into a target-tag you do need the `link_with` statement. By default cocoapods only links the pods to the first target.

Comment: Ok so I left everything as is and added your code at the end of my Podfile, but I'm getting this warning after doing a `pod install`: CocoaPods did not set the base configuration of your project because your project already has a custom config set. In order for CocoaPods integration to work at all, please either set the base configurations of the target `MainTarget`

Comment: have you tried to put all pods in a `target` Tag andere drop the `link_with` line!?

Comment: Yes I get the same warnings :/

Comment: try deleting all pod related files (pods directory, workspace, pods.lock) and do a `pod install` again